# MS Access VBA: Optional Argument Does Not Assume Default Value

Tags: ms-access, vba

I imagine this is an easy one.  I have the following declarations:

```
Public Const TABLE_MY_TABLE As String = "my_table"

Sub reloadProjections(startDate As String, endDate As String, _
                      Optional tableName As String = TABLE_MY_TABLE)

   'Processing occurs here

End Sub
```

For some reason, when the optional argument is not supplied, tableName does not assume the default value of TABLE_MY_TABLE.  When you step through this with a debugger, TABLE_MY_TABLE is set to "my_table" and tableName is an empty string.  Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me. How are you calling it? Try, say:

```
 reloadProjections date(),date()
```

Comment: Good grief - I feel dumb! :)  Yes, it works fine.  I was staring at the wrong chuck of code.  It was passing the argument (not using the default as I assumed) and I misspelled the argument name, so it was passing an empty string.  The joys of a loosely-typed language.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Er, what? Loosely typed? If you have OPTION EXPLICIT turned on, you wouldn't be able to compile code with misspelled variable names. That's remedial Access -- you also use OPTION EXPLICIT in all your modules.